# WPF Binding does not update Button-Content

Tags: c#, wpf, ivalueconverter

May someone tell me whats wrong with this sourcecode?
when i click the button its not updating ist value?
At first binding the converter makes his job.

the sourcecode is pretty big so i will post only some snippets.

XAML: 
Instances is type of ObservableCollection

```
<ListBox Name="Instances">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Tag="{Binding Path=Instance.Name}" Content="{Binding Path=Instance.Active, Converter={StaticResource BTSC}}" Click="ChangeAccess"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Instance.Name}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Converter:

```
public class BoolToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (((Boolean)value) == true)
            return "No";
        else
            return "Yes";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Event:

```
private void ChangeAccess(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for...
    if ((sender as Button).Tag.ToString() == (DP.Instances[i].Instance as CInstance).Name)
    {
        SkipIfAndElse...
        DP.Instances[i].Instance.Active = true;
    }
}
```

CInstance:

```
class CInstance : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Boolean active;
    public Boolean Active
    {
        get { return active; }
        set
        {
            active = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Access");
        }
    }
}
```

All other values of the CInstance class are updating as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your CInstance class

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("Access");
```

should be

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("Active");
```

Comment: Oh my god, thanks a lot. im sitting here for hours and oversight this Little bug every time. Sorry for crap-posting

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you start using some kind of INPC framework. I personally like Simon Cropp's [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody).
Fody adds the appropriate OnNotifyPropertyChanged as a post compilation step, which means you don't get the Runtime hit that you get with Expression based solutions.

At the end of the day, string based OnNotifyPropertyChanged are all pretty fragile.